# How to append array to existing json javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a json object like:

```
{
   name: "Julia"
   birthdate: "xxxx"
   movies: [{title: "movie1", rating: 5}, {title: "movie2", rating 3}}]
}
```

I want to do something like:

```
var myobj = [];
myobj.push({name: "Julia", birthdate: "xxxx"});

myobj.movies = [];
myobj.movies.push({title: "movie1", rating: 5});
myobj.movies.push({title: "movie2", rating: 3});
```

But I am unable to create that "movies" part. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are creating the object as an array. You have to create as an object to add properties:

```
var myobj = {name: "Julia", birthdate: "xxxx"};

myobj.movies = []; 
myobj.movies.push({title: "movie1", rating: 5}); 
myobj.movies.push({title: "movie2", rating: 3});
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix datatypes(push works only on Arrays and attributes with objects), try something like this:

```
var myobj = {};
myobj.persons = [];
myobj.persons.push({name: "Julia", birthdate: "xxxx"});

myobj.movies = [];
myobj.movies.push({title: "movie1", rating: 5});
myobj.movies.push({title: "movie2", rating: 3});
```

Answer (score 1):

ye this works

`var myobj = [];
    myobj.push({name: "Julia", birthdate: "xxxx"});`

```
myobj.push({movies: []});

myobj.movies = [];
myobj.movies.push({title: "movie1", rating: 5});
myobj.movies.push({title: "movie2", rating: 3});

console.log(myobj);</code>
```